# Find upper limit of an integration

Tags: r

Anyone know how to write in r code to find the upper limit, $y,$ for $\int_0^y f(x) \, dx= \operatorname{unif}(1,0,1)$?

**EDIT**:

For example, $f(x)=2x+x^3$ and $\operatorname{unif}(1,0,1)=0.6$

So, $\int_0^y f(x) \, dx = y^2 + \frac{y^4}{4} = 0.6$

Therefore, $y^2 + \frac{y^4}{4} - 0.6 = 0$ and let $u=y^2$ gives $u^2 + 4u - 2.4 = 0$ then solved it and get $y=0.7279$ and $y=\sqrt{-4.5298}$

**But my $f(x)$ is not as simple as in the example. I need a general r coding for any function, $f(x)$, in which can get the upper limit of integration, $y$, when the area of the integration is randomly generated by the uniform distribution in between 0 and 1.**

Comment: what is unif(1,0,1)?

Comment: randomize a value from uniform distribution in between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you know how to find the answer analytically? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567014/what-does-it-mean-to-solve-a-math-problem-analytically

Comment: I just coded the solution to your answer in Python, unfortunately, in R I am having problems...

Comment: For example, my $f(x)=2x+x^3$ and $\operatorname{unif}(1,0,1)=0.6$

So, $\int_0^y f(x) \, dx = y^2 + \frac{y^4}{4}$ and gives $y^2 + \frac{y^4}{4} = 0.6$.

Therefore, $y^2 + \frac{y^4}{4} - 0.6 = 0$ and let $u=y^2$ gives $u^2 + 4u - 2.4 = 0$ then solved it to get $y=0.7279$ and $y=\sqrt{-4.5298}$. Please take note that my $f(x)$ is not this simple.

Comment: Thank you David on your effort, but I really need it in R

Comment: The function `f_x <- function(x) {2*x + x**3}`. The integral in terms of the function `int_f <- function(x) {integrate(f_x, lower = 0, upper = x)}`. Random number `num = runif(1, 0, 1)`. Know the number `num`. Another function `tru_f <- function(x) {  ff <- int_f(x); ff$value - num}`. Find the answer `uniroot(tru_f, lower = 0, upper = 2)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86200/discussion-between-david-and-alicia).